# Unable to open a session without Screen with many tabs

Tags: gnu-screen

My .zshrc has the following

```
 if [[ $STY = '' ]]; then
          screen -aADxR 
 fi
```

I have many Screen "tabs" open. I would like to stop Screen only in one Screen's tab such that I can run commands which I cannot run inside Screen.

I run unsuccessfully

```
screen -d
```

which closes one tab.

It may be easier to open a new tab apparently to get a tab without Screen. However, if I open a new tab (not-terminal-tab) in Screen, it opens it inside Screen because of the code in my .zshrc.

**How can you close/open Screen in one tab such that other tabs are not closed in Screen?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do Ctrl+A,D which will detach that one session.

That's an interesting trick with screen.

Comment: I did not get `Ctrl+A D` to work with my code, neither without it. -- I get the following when I press `Ctrl+A D`: http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/screen-detach-problem.png

Comment: Sorry, it should be Ctrl+A d (i.e. lowercase). The normal detach command, in other words.